# When I Enter start date like 1/9/2017 for 12 month so how to find the end date as per calculation of 12 months after

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I Enter start date like 1/9/2017 for 12 month 
so how to find the end date as per calculation of 12 months after.

Comment: `date.AddYears(1)`?

Comment: If someone enters `29/2/2016` what do *you* consider to be twelve months later? Similar questions arise for `28/2/2015` and `1/3/2015`. What rules do you want to use here?

Comment: Also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29362830/c-sharp-not-adding-a-year-with-addyears1

Comment: `System.DateTime` has plenty of options for this. Please explain why they do not satisfy your needs.

Comment: i want to do agreement fot 11 months but when i start agreement for todays date but i can not find end date. i find manually but i want to do in programmatically.

Comment: Please establish some context while asking a question. you have thrown a question here which hardly makes any sense.
What do you mean by "When I Enter start date like 1/9/2017 for 12 month"

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this assuming that 1/9/2017 is dd/mm/yyyy. If not then just switch 1 and 9 around.

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 9, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddMonths(12);
```